# Video streaming from server to Android app

Tags: android, spring, video-streaming

I have a server builded with Spring where users can upload images and videos. 
Now I am building an Android app where users should watch these videos throught streaming, but I am little bit lost about how to handle this.

I have looking for information about how to do this, and I am not sure if I could do with a Spring REST method.

What is the best way to do this? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To stream the video you can use Vitamio library on Android. Handles many types of formats. Depending on how you send the streams, you can use native players to play. I did this using rtsp links from server, you can play around with it

Comment: @paul_hundal I will take a look, thanks :)

Comment: I'm an about to the same for a school project.Did you find a solution or anything useful you would share?

Comment: @Dokuzov Finally, due to time constraints, I had to abandon the streaming funcionality. Sorry, I can´t help you.

Comment: Alright , thanks for the reply anyways.